# how to create a file with line of text in Linux

Tags: linux, echo

Create a file bash/alx with these two lines inside: `#!/bin/bash` and `echo "ALX"` in linux
I have tried this:

```sh
touch bash/alx 
touch '#!/bin/bash'
```

Answer (score 2):

`touch` is a command that creates or updates the timestamp on a file.

`echo foo` outputs `foo` to stdout.

If you use output redirection, `echo foo > bar` puts `foo` into the file `bar`.

Combining these will give you your solution.

```sh
touch /path/t/myFileName
echo "text for file" > /path/to/myFileName
```

[This page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/input-output-redirection-in-linux/) has some good information.

Answer (score 2):

To create a file in Linux using touch,the syntax is:

```sh
touch /path/to/your/file
touch alx.txt # E.g
```

You can echo something in a file using (by default `echo` output to stdout):

```sh
echo content > file
# or
echo content >> file
```

The former override the file content if it already exist or create it while the latter will append your content to the file if it exists or create it too.
Thus you can use `echo` directly without needing to use touch to create the file before.

And as you can pass options to Linux commands, `echo` has `-e` that instructs it to interpret special chars like `\n` in your string. So you can send multiple lines to a file with `echo -e "line1\nline2\n..." > somewhere.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text editor like vi to create that file.

in terminal just type:

```bash
vi filename
```